# Dynamics Online (2011) crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using Dynamics Online (2011). I'm trying to make a field required based on a client selection, but to get me started I've written the below script to make the field required regardless of their selection. However when I run call this function I get the following error. any help would be highly appropriated.

```
 function updateProductAreaRequirement() {


    try {
        crmForm.SetFieldReqLevel("pt_productarea", 1);
    }
    catch(err) {

        alert("Error : " + err);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using CRM 4 JavaScript, try the newer CRM 2011 syntax.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pt_productarea").setRequiredLevel("required");
```

[Xrm.Page Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Please read this discussion [discussion](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6d39f7a-535c-46ce-a48b-a984e32feceb/problem-with-crmformsetfieldreqlevel-method). Someone has suggested a workaround for the same issue. I hope it will help you.

```
crmForm.all.<fieldname>Select.children[1].bCached = false;
```